# Why USERGROUPS_ENAB property in /etc/login.defs does not have any effect?

Tags: permissions, pam, umask

I just found the following comment in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
# Enable setting of the umask group bits to be the same as owner bits
# (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007) for non-root users, if the uid is
# the same as gid, and username is the same as the primary group name.
```

This sounds cool, but it doesn't behave like that on my system:

```
me@mysystem ~ $ id
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) Gruppen=1000(me),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),100(users),113(lpadmin),130(sambashare),133(roccat)
me@mysystem ~ $ touch test
me@mysystem ~ $ ll test
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Aug 17 20:02 test
me@mysystem ~ $ rm test
me@mysystem ~ $
```

(following replacements were made (nothing else): my_real_user_and_groupname => me, my_real_hostname => mysystem)

My primary group is my personal group (as the group assignment of the test file shows), but I don't know a CLI command to check this. I checked it via GUI instead.

Anyone knows why the behaviour described in this comment does not affect my environment?
Or cleaner: why is `test` created with `-rw-r--r--` instead of `-rw-rw-r--` on my system?

---

Update:

```
me@mysystem ~ $ cat .bashrc | grep -e umask -e UMASK
me@mysystem ~ $ cat .profile | grep -e umask -e UMASK
# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022
me@mysystem ~ $ cat /etc/profile | grep -e umask -e UMASK
me@mysystem ~ $ cat /etc/bash.bashrc | grep -e umask -e UMASK
me@mysystem ~ $ umask 
0022
me@mysystem ~ $
```

---

Update 2

```
me@mysystem / $ grep -r 'umask [0-9]' /etc/ 2> /dev/null
/etc/init/ssh.conf:umask 022
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/0dns-down:umask 022
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0dns-up:umask 022
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/samba: umask 022
/etc/init.d/umountfs:umask 022
/etc/init.d/ssh:umask 022
/etc/init.d/resolvconf: umask 022
/etc/init.d/urandom:    umask 077
/etc/init.d/urandom:    umask 022
/etc/init.d/urandom:    umask 077
/etc/init.d/rc:umask 022
/etc/skel/.profile:#umask 022
/etc/X11/Xsession:if (umask 077 && touch "$ERRFILE") 2> /dev/null && [ -w "$ERRFILE" ] &&
me@mysystem / $
```

Comment: Please help me improve my skills with providing me information on why my question was downvoted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This file takes effect when you are logging into the system and set things up for once.

If you run:

```
$ grep ^UMASK /etc/login.defs 
UMASK       022
```

You can see that the default `UMASK` is `022` and if you check its comments you will find out that:

> If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value for private user groups.

Open a terminal and run:

```
umask
```

You should get `002` because of `USERGROUPS_ENAB` being enabled, otherwise you are overwriting `umask`'s value somewhere else like:

```
.bashrc
.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: This is exactly what is not the case for me, see my updated question. Btw. this is like that on all of my systems, so I think this is the default state of Ubuntu after installation.

Comment: See if this command finds any file that is setting `umask` : `grep -r 'umask [0-9]' /etc/ 2> /dev/null`

Comment: (OT: Hey wow this is a cool command!) I updated my question with the output. Not sure, how to interpret the output, but there seems to be no umask 002 anywhere... (by the way, it's not quite true that we are wondering that USERGROUP_ENAB has no effect at all, cause it has another effect that is working: add personal group as main group at user creation)

Comment: The default `umask` is being set as `022` in `login.defs` however `USERGROUPS_ENAB` should change it to `002` which it does however there are bunch of places where `umask` value from `002` is being overwritten to: `022`. I don't know which one of these files are responsible of doing this... but one should be.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand. So maybe it is `/etc/init.d/rc` where the `umask` is set to `022` at the top and without condition. The comment header of the script tells that it `Starts/stops services on runlevel changes`. So maybe my login session is started by this script? The other occurrences woudn't make sense as far as I understand these things...